# Interacting with a Re-Captcha via http post

Tags: javascript, python, html, captcha

Is this possible? I would appreciate any input here.

The website has a typical form base, but then has your typical catcha

```
snippet from form

  <input type='password' name='password2' autocomplete='off' id='password2' maxlength='20' placeholder="Confirm Password" class='account-form__input-text account-form__input-text--password' title="Confirm Password" value='testpass' pattern='.{5,20}' required />
            <span class='account-form__hint account-form__hint--password2' data-content="Please confirm the password you entered above">?</span>
        </div>
        <label class='account-form__news-label' for='news-updates'><input class='account-form__check' type='checkbox' name='agree_email' id='news-updates' checked />Please send me News and Updates</label>
                        <div class='account-form__captcha' id='g-recaptcha' data-theme='dark' data-error="Please complete the reCAPTCHA box."></div>



    <script>
        var myCap, onloadCallback = function() {
            myCap = grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
                'sitekey': '6LccFA0TAAAAAHEwUJx_c1TfTBWMTAOIphwTtd1b',
                'expired-callback': resetCap,
                'theme': 'dark'
            });
        };
        function resetCap(){
            grecaptcha.reset();
        }
    </script>
```

Any ideas on how I would go about implementing and interacting with this re-captcha in python?